# Do javascript console and DOM tree exist in Atom editor?

Tags: javascript, dom, atom-editor, console.log

I have a page, index.html, and I'd like to see the DOM tree for the page, plus the javascript console output from this page only. Currently I am seeing a DOM tree (View > Developer > Toggle developer tools) for the entire Atom Editor, but I can only drill down as far as an <  object  > with type browser-plugin - I can't see the html elements of my page, such as SVG. And when I type console.log('whatever'); nothing shows in the console - again, Atom seems to be focused on logs from loading the Atom Editor, rather than loading index.html.

I'm being asked to use this text editor by a client, but I don't see how I can use it without these features working. Does anyone know if they're available and where they are?

Thanks
Emma

Comment: Normally if you wanted to test a webpage you would use a web browser to do it, not a text editor.

Comment: Thanks. Doing this locally via Chrome I get 'cross-origin request' errors when loading my CSV and XML data. I'm trying to demonstrate to students - and don't want to load to server for each tiny change in code

Comment: Run a local server then.

Comment: Thanks, yes I can do, but I don't want to spend half the course explaining to students what a local server is. It's an online video course and they will be mimicking my set-up. The problem goes away if I can find a text editor with a preview and console (as with Coda 2). But my client understandably wants the text editor to be free across Mac / windows. I take it from your response that the Atom editor has no plug-in or solution for this?

Comment: I've no idea. The 10 seconds it takes to type `php -S 0.0.0.0:7007` means I've never had the need to try to hack my editor into being an IDE.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Looks like Firefox and Firebug will be able to do what Chrome cannot (unusually).

Answer (score -1):

Atom is not a WYSIWYG editor, to see the the DOM tree you'll need to open the file in your browser and test it there. Or you could maybe use this plugin https://atom.io/packages/atom-html-preview . not sure if you can access the DOM tree there. You'll need to try that.